# Can you create a new project in builder

Tags: gnome, 16.04, gnome-builder

I have recently installed builder on my pc (Ubuntu Gnome Xerius). When you open it you only see a white window with in the top left corner a button 'new'. When you press that you can choose to create a project from an existing project on your computer or from a remote source code repository. But I just want to create a new project. Is this possible?

If it isn't: Where would you use builder for if you cannot start new projects.